# How do you modify the URL of a page without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, html, web-development-server

I am creating a webpage and I would like to know how to modify or change the URL without reloading the whole entire page.

Comment: I think you have it backwards.  You can modify the page while keeping the same URL but not vice-versa.

Comment: What should that be good for, except to confuse the user or provide misleading information?

Comment: @Nelles that is not correct. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState

Answer (score 1):

You might get some mileage out of reading about the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) in modern browsers.

The JavaScript functions `window.history.back()` and `window.history.forward()` have the capacity to update the URL without reloading the page.

The [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Browser_compatibility) is pretty vast, so I wouldn't hesitate about using it, personally.